# Unsupported report type Error on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports

I am trying to create a Pipeline Development Report where I need to Group Stages and use Historical Trending Report but when I add this report on Dashboard, an error occurs saying:

> Unsupported report type

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here just in case it can help someone - Mine was the "Campaigns with Influenced Opportunities" report type. I realized that the report type changed once we switched to the updated influence for Lightning. You have to recreate the report using the "Campaigns with Influenced Opportunities (Customizable Campaign Influence)" report type. Then it works!!